# Compiler Error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_6 when using Rccp classes.

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am just getting used to working with the Rcpp package in R. I usually build a package when using Rcpp. To debug and test, however, I would like to be able to run c++ code without involving R all the time. Thus, I tried to use Rccp classes in a c++ program. The example

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Rcpp::NumericVector vec(0);

    return 0;
}
```

produces the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_REprintf", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::xsputn(char const*, long) in main-fe5efc.o
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::overflow(int) in main-fe5efc.o
  "_R_FlushConsole", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::sync() in main-fe5efc.o
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::sync() in main-fe5efc.o
  "_R_GetCCallable", referenced from:
      dataptr(SEXPREC*) in main-fe5efc.o
  "_R_NilValue", referenced from:
      Rcpp::PreserveStorage<Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >::PreserveStorage() in main-fe5efc.o
      Rcpp::PreserveStorage<Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >::~PreserveStorage() in main-fe5efc.o
      Rcpp::Rcpp_ReleaseObject(SEXPREC*) in main-fe5efc.o
      Rcpp::Rcpp_PreserveObject(SEXPREC*) in main-fe5efc.o
  "_R_PreserveObject", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rcpp_PreserveObject(SEXPREC*) in main-fe5efc.o
  "_R_ReleaseObject", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rcpp_ReleaseObject(SEXPREC*) in main-fe5efc.o
  "_Rf_allocVector", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::Vector(int const&) in main-fe5efc.o
  "_Rf_isNull", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rcpp_ReplaceObject(SEXPREC*, SEXPREC*) in main-fe5efc.o
  "_Rf_xlength", referenced from:
      void Rcpp::internal::r_init_vector<14>(SEXPREC*) in main-fe5efc.o
  "_Rprintf", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::xsputn(char const*, long) in main-fe5efc.o
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::overflow(int) in main-fe5efc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I compile using the following command:

```
clang++ main.cpp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"
```

I am on a Mac using Xcode 6. Looking for a solution I already installed both Rcpp and RInside from source, but it did not fix the problem. Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rcpp is an R extension. It simply cannot work without R.

You simply made a heroic assumption that you could do what you are doing. Turns out that that assumption is incorrect.

Your closest bet, it you want to build new 'main' programs, is to use [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) which embeds R.  Start with its numerous examples, particular in `examples/standard/`.